# Underscore.js template rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have this sample code to render simple unescapedHTML using underscore templating.

```
var template = $(this.el).html(_.template(this.template, {'data': '&lt;script&gt;'}));
$(this.parent).append(template);
```

But when it try to render it, it caused an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'

Can anyone please enlighten me what's the cause and how to solve it? Since in underscore documentation:

```
var template = _.template("<b>&lt;%- value %></b>");
template({value : '&lt;script&gt;'});
=> "<b>&lt;script&gt;</b>"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `this.template`? A string or, perhaps, a DOM or jQuery object?

Comment: Yes, its jQuery object. Also, when I'd tried to use that example from underscore documentation, it also throw error: 'value' is not defined although I'd enclosed it with string.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> **template** `_.template(templateString, [context])`
>
> Compiles JavaScript templates into functions that can be evaluated for rendering.

The first argument for `_.template` is supposed to be a string, not a jQuery object. Part of the internal processing for `_.template` calls the [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function and that's where your error comes from. You might want to use this instead:

```
var template = $(this.el).html(_.template(this.template.html(), {'data': '<script>'}));
$(this.parent).append(template);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wPu6G/

The example you give works just fine:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/w2qWe/

So I don't know where the *'value' is not defined* error you mention in your comment could be coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the same error while running node on the server.  If you read the template file from disk and you don't specify the encoding then node.js will return a buffer.  The error is basically the same because Underscore expects a string.  Make sure that you specify an encoding so that you are passing a string to Underscore.

this will produce the error.

```
var template = _.template(fs.readFileSync('mytemplate.tpl'));
```

and this is good.

```
var template = _.template(fs.readFileSync('mytemplate.tpl', { 'encoding':'utf8'}));
```